# Radiobutton Even Horizontal Alignment

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Is there a way to evenly layout radiobuttons including the radiobutton text? I have tried StackPanel with Orientation=Horizontal, DockPanel and UniformGrid but I have not achieved the exact look I am going for which is an even amount of white space between the controls without having to wrap or truncate the text.

[image: StackPanel Alignment Horizontal]

[image: UniformGrid One Row]

```
<GroupBox Name="grpLegend" Header="{x:Static res:Strings.ChartOptionsDisplayControlView_GroupBox_Legend}">
                <ItemsControl
                    ItemsSource="{Binding IsAsync=True, Path=AvailablePitchbookLegendPosition}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton
                                Content="{Binding IsAsync=True, Path=DisplayName}"
                                IsChecked="{Binding IsAsync=True, Path=IsSelected}"
                                GroupName="LegendPosition"
                                Margin="2,3.5" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Content="Left"/>
    <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Center"/>
    <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Content="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

If this Grid was part of a list's ItemTemplate and you wanted to synchronize the widths of the grid's columns you should use the SharedSizeGroup property.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="c1"/>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="c2"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="c3"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Content="Left"/>
    <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Center"/>
    <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Content="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

and then on a suitable parent container use the attached property Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true"

```
<ListBox Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ItemTemplate={StaticResource RadioButtonTemplate}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That definitely works with static items. I was wondering how this would work with a dynamic collection and therefore a potentially variable number of radiobuttons.

Comment: Updated answer.  Look up Grid.IsSharedSizeScope for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for that. I know that your answer works but I haven't been able to apply it successfully to my ItemsControl. I'm confused as to how you bind collection data to a template containing 3 radiobuttons rather than one. If I do that I just get 9 radiobuttons rather than 3. That's just my lack of XAML knowledge though.

Comment: I thought you meant a list of groups of three radio buttons.  Do you actually mean a variable length list of radio buttons?

Comment: That's correct I did mean a variable length list of radiobuttons. At the end of the day the number of radiobuttons is unlikely to change so I could change my ViewModel to bind differently (e.g. a unique property for each radiobutton) but currently each radiobutton is dynamically created based on a collection of objects and the length of that collection could change. I just wanted a way to evenly space them according to the available horizontal space. UniformGrid does not allocate more horizontal space to the longer item. It gives equal space to each which looks strange. Thanks for your help.